# How to prevent keyboard from closing when Android back button is pressed in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, back-button

You can override the Android back button function in react native by using `BackHandler`. However, when the keyboard is open and the back button is pressed instead of entering the `hardwareBackPress` listener the keyboard closes.

Comment: That is standard Android behavior.

Comment: I know but I am searching for a workaround.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @RyanPergent Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be some like this

```
state = { keyboardopen: false };

BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackPress);

Keyboard.addListener(
  "keyboardDidShow",

  () => this.setState({ keyboardopen: !keyboardopen })
);

handleBackPress = () => {
  if (keyboardopen) {
    // do some thing
  } else {
    //do some thing else
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that when the back button is pressed while the keyboard is open it doesn't enter the `handleBackPress` method.